# Why am I unable to color my volumetric clouds white?

Tags: shaders, light, color, volumetrics

I am trying to render a cover of white clouds as seen from above. I am using the Principled Volume shader, using gradient and noise textures. It now looks as follows:

[image: Volumetric cloud setup]

However, the clouds are very dark (even though I set the color to white), and I don't know how to change this. I put a purple sun light with maximum strength right above, but it only colors some contours. I've also tried HDR environment maps. How can I get the clouds to be white, just like real life clouds on a sunny day?

Answer (score 1):

After replicating your node network I found reducing the anisitropy value on the principled volume node makes the clouds whiter

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It alleviated the problem, but didn't really solve it, as the base color still was black.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by scaling down my entire scene. Apparently large-scale clouds aren't rendered correctly, and in my case there was a pretty clear threshold at which it started showing its base color.

Answer (score 1):

Turn up *Max Bounces* -> *Volume* or the ray will be reported as lost if it bounces into the volume and not immediately to a light source.

[image]

Once bounces are increased you can multiply the density to get a thicker volume appearance.

For very very large volumes it may be appropriate to introduce a little bit of emission just to emulate atmospheric scattering without the computational cost.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue in eevee :
the volume shader appeared black.

i figured a solution (blender 3.5):

- use the Principled Volume Shader
- set color to black !! (do not ask me why)
- set density to 0.001 (do not ask me why)
- finally, control the white intensity:  with the emission-strength slider (0.008) !
- do not forget to set the blend mode of the volume to AlphaBlend or AlphaHashed (in material settings)

image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if volume has an attribute 'dencity' you can plug it to blackbody to make it whiter, but you should use low values for multiplier to get good result

with dencity attribute:
[image: with dencity attribute:]

without dencity attribute:
[image: without dencity attribute:]